# Only include line starts with number

Tags: javascript, html

I want to include only lines that start with the sequence number and remove all other lines. Here is the code which I am trying, please help! Refer to the image for more understanding.

**Image**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dVCE.png

Thanks in Advance

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/PriyankaJain/gnwhjbyf/

```
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
<br />
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
<html>
<body>
<h10 style="color: red;">*Write/paste your text, then click on "Convert" button, this will only include sequence number lines and remove all other lines. Now you can copy your text by clicking "Copy Text!" button. You can reset everything by clicking "Clear All!" button.</h10>


<center>
<form>

  <textarea autocomplete="off" cols="30" id="TextInput1" name="message" rows="10" style="border: 3px solid #73AD21; width: 40%;"></textarea>  

  <textarea autocomplete="off" cols="30" id="TextInput2" name="message" rows="10" style="border: 3px solid #73AD21; width: 40%;"></textarea>

  <input id="WhiteSpaceRemove" onclick="myFunction()" style="border: 3px solid #73AD21;" type="button" value="Convert" />

   <input id="ClearAll" onclick="ClearAllText()" style="border: 3px solid #73AD21;" type="button" value="Clear All!" />

<input id="CopyButton" onclick="CopyFunction()" style="border: 3px solid #73AD21;" type="button" value="Copy Text!" /><br />

</form>
</center>
<script>
function ClearAllText() {
document.getElementById("TextInput1").value = "";
document.getElementById("TextInput2").value = "";
}



function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("TextInput1").value.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ", ");
  document.getElementById("TextInput2").value.match(/^\d/) = x;
document.getElementById("CopyButton").value="Copy Text!"; 
}

function CopyFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("TextInput2");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");

document.getElementById("CopyButton").value="Copied";  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
</div>
<b>Tags: </b></div>
</div>


  [1]:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this ok? It's mostly your code, I only changed the `myFunction`.

```js
function ClearAllText() {
  document.getElementById("TextInput1").value = "";
  document.getElementById("TextInput2").value = "";
}

function myFunction() {
  const x = document.getElementById("TextInput1").value.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '\n');
  const lines = x.split('\n');
  const numberedLines = lines.filter(line => /^\d/.test(line));
  document.getElementById("TextInput2").value = numberedLines.join('\n');
}

function CopyFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("TextInput2");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");

  document.getElementById("CopyButton").value = "Copied";
}
```

```html
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
  <br />
  <div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
    <div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
      <html>

      <body>
        <h10 style="color: red;">*Write/paste your text, then click on "Convert" button, this will only include sequence number lines and remove all other lines. Now you can copy your text by clicking "Copy Text!" button. You can reset everything by clicking "Clear All!" button.</h10>


        <center>
          <form>

            <textarea autocomplete="off" cols="30" id="TextInput1" name="message" rows="10" style="border: 3px solid #73AD21; width: 40%;"></textarea>

            <textarea autocomplete="off" cols="30" id="TextInput2" name="message" rows="10" style="border: 3px solid #73AD21; width: 40%;"></textarea>

            <input id="WhiteSpaceRemove" onclick="myFunction()" style="border: 3px solid #73AD21;" type="button" value="Convert" />

            <input id="ClearAll" onclick="ClearAllText()" style="border: 3px solid #73AD21;" type="button" value="Clear All!" />

            <input id="CopyButton" onclick="CopyFunction()" style="border: 3px solid #73AD21;" type="button" value="Copy Text!" /><br />

          </form>
        </center>

      </body>

      </html>
    </div>
    <b>Tags: </b></div>
</div>
```